# Efficiently convert string based time into milliseconds

Tags: javascript

I was given a challenge, to create a function that'd convert a string based time into milliseconds.

That's the string format I was given:

> "hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds"

So this value for example will need to return 3010220.

> "0:50:10.220"

The function needs to be short and one lined.
I'd love to know where I could improve the function below as it didn't pass the criteria. how can this be turned into a one liner?

```
function toMilliseconds(time){
  return time.match(/[0-9]+/g).map(function(val,s,a){
    return s != 3 ? +val * ((Math.pow(60,a.length - s -2) * 1000)) : +val;
  }).reduce(function(a,b){
    return a+b;
  },0);
}
```

Comment: "The function needs to be short and one lined." - Why does it need be one lined? Seems like a terrible requirement

Comment: Where does the challenge come from? Are you allowed to seek help?

Comment: How does `0:50` become `30`?  Should it be `0.5` (half an hour)?

Comment: @tymeJV, cause one line goez fasta :)

Comment: @Redicate, possibly better ask this on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Archer it is 50 minutes

Comment: @tymeJV It was one of the criteria for the challenge. that's it.

Comment: @Radicate - In that case, just remove your line breaks - donezo.

Comment: _The function needs to be short and one lined._ Any obfuscated/compressed JS code is one-lined.

Comment: @putvande It was in an interview I went to and failed because of that haha, just curious as to how others would've solved it.

Comment: If it's 50 minutes then you need to explain how that relates to the 30 in the answer.

Comment: What a terrible interview criteria as well :\

Comment: @Archer Google "50 minutes to milliseconds"

Comment: answered here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45335/milliseconds-to-time-string-time-string-to-milliseconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways.

This is the shortest way I can think of (using ES6):

```js
var str = "0:50:10.220";

var ms = (s=>1E3*s[2]+6E4*s[1]+36E5*s[0])(str.split(':'));

console.log(ms);
```

Comment: This is getting crazy =D

Comment: @robertklep Quite crazy indeed :o

Comment: Here's another one: `((a,b,c)=>+c+b*60+a*3600)(...str.split(':'))*1E3`

Comment: @robertklep Nice one!

Comment: We could also use destructuring: `1E3*(([a,b,c])=>+c+b*60+a*3600)(str.split(':'))`

Answer (score 2):

And another one:

```
let ms = str.split(':').reduce((a,v,i) => a + v * [3600000, 60000, 1000, 1][i], 0)
```

**EDIT**, thanks to @Swonkie:

```
let ms = str.split(':').reduce((a,v,i) => a + v * [3600000, 60000, 1000][i], 0)
```

Which leads to (thanks @Arnauld):

```
let ms = str.split(':').reduce((a,v,i)=>a+v*1E3*[3600,60,1][i],0);
```

Or, with rounding (not at all tested for validity):

```
let ms = str.split(':').reduce((a,v,i)=>a+v*1E3*[3600,60,1][i],0.5)|0;
```

Comment: The array has only 3 elements (h, m, s with decimals), so the last `, 1` is not required in your code.

Comment: '0:0:1.001'.split(':').reduce((a,v,i)=>a+v*1000*[3600,60,1][i],0); //1000.9999999999999

Comment: You can shorten this some more: `1000` => `1E3` ;-)

Comment: Rounding added for @AdamFischer (+ thanks @ Arnauld)

Answer (score -1):

As described here:

> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45335/milliseconds-to-time-string-time-string-to-milliseconds

this looks like good solution:

```
function timeString2ms(a,b){// time(HH:MM:SS.mss) // optimized
 return a=a.split('.'), // optimized
  b=a[1]*1||0, // optimized
  a=a[0].split(':'),
  b+(a[2]?a[0]*3600+a[1]*60+a[2]*1:a[1]?a[0]*60+a[1]*1:a[0]*1)*1e3 // optimized
}
```

"oneline solution"

```
function timeString2ms2(a,b){ return a=a.split('.'),b=a[1]*1||0,a=a[0].split(':'),b+(a[2]?a[0]*3600+a[1]*60+a[2]*1:a[1]?a[0]*60+a[1]*1:a[0]*1)*1e3 }
```

Usage

```
console.log(timeString2ms('10:21:32.093')); // hh:mm:ss.mss
console.log(timeString2ms('21:32.093')); // mm:ss.mss
console.log(timeString2ms('21:32')); // mm:ss
console.log(timeString2ms('32.093')); // ss.mss 
console.log(timeString2ms('32')); // ss
console.log(timeString2ms('32467.784'));  // seconds.ms
console.log(timeString2ms(32467.784+'')); // seconds.ms
```

Comment: Its not 1 line though. And its better to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: updated my answer for "one-line" solution. But it is the same answer, just less readable tho.. And I can not tag duplicate outside SO